# Providing access to user for all folders and connection in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have created one user in Informatica and i wanted to provide access to that user to all existing folder and connections in one go.
Please let me know if there is any way to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the user to Administrator Group? Or you just want to give permissions for folders and connections ?